# Google App Engine - Blobstore request working on production not in development

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, blob, blobstore

I'm using google app engine to develop an upload form to upload a csv file.
The issue I'm currently having is that in a Development environment the request action is to being sent correctly.

In the production environment the request action seems to work although the action is the same for both forms.

E.g.

Development

```
   action="http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ag50cy1zY2gtcmVwb3J0c3IbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGAEM"
```

Production action:

```
    action="http://website.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6Yer2BJaT_tW_fmc- PKvHaOHD3pnv5QH6o6d8XQQujbCWg5egbjf2sGxP5_cN6uAyvgDVOn8U40wLLXEvoQcrMDbHQQByJpTlamzBPz_8x8LN2UWKM/ALBNUaYAAAAAT1EmxMkvj7tiS9WAvYAWKPG1sN1DvmMk/"
```

When I investigate within the logs, the development server states the action is:
"/ag50cy1zY2gtcmVwb3J0c3IbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGAEM"

Where as the Production logs state the action is:
"/form" (as expected)

The code for both is the same underneath as follows.

file: upload.jsp

```
    <%
               request.getAttribute("message");

                BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
            %>

            <hr/>
            <p>Upload a .csv file to the system.</p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Upload File</legend>
                <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload/form") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="filename_1">File: </label>
                    <input id="filename_1" type="file" id="filename_1" name="file" size="30" onchange="checkInput();" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Upload File" />
                </form>
            </fieldset>
```

file: controller.java

```
    else if (action.equals("/form")) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller3.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, action);

            Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
            List<BlobKey> bkList = blobs.get("filename_1");
            BlobKey blobKey = bkList.get(0);

            if (blobKey == null) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller3.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Blob null");
                response.sendRedirect("/");
            } else {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller3.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Blob not null");
                FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

                // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
                AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);// Again, different standard Java ways of reading from the channel.
                FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
                Reader reader1 = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));

                char c = ',';
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(reader1, c);

                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results = reader.getResults();
                ArrayList<String> columns = reader.getColumns();

                request.setAttribute("maxColumns", columns);
                request.setAttribute("csvResults", results);

                //Remove the CSV file from the blobstore now we have used it.
                blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
                this.getServletContext().setAttribute("csvUploadResults", results);
            }
```

The web.xml has been setup to to deal with the requests:
/_ah/upload/*, /upload/*, /_ah/upload/upload/*

I'm hoping there is a simple explaination (there probably is) why the code works in production but not in development.

Any assistance will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently wrestling with the Blobstore too.

I note you said:
The web.xml has been setup to to deal with the requests: /_ah/upload/, /upload/, /_ah/upload/upload/*

But note that AFTER the blobstore has handled the request to add your blob (by posting to the URL you got createUploadUrl("/upload") ) Then it will call YOUR method mapped to "/upload" in web.xml.  So you definitely want to remove any web.xml references to /_ah/upload/ as that is what the blobstore will intercept.

I did that for a while and was getting a server error 500 with no logging whatsoever.

Comment: I found a workaround the the problem. I did as you said removed the /_ah/* from the web.xml.

I also created a new servlet to deal with just the upload function. I'm not too sure how this helped, but the system is now working as expected.

Comment: great, glad to hear it helped.(can I have a credit plz;)  I did the same too a few days ago.  By the way for anyone else struggling with this API, I found another big GOTCHA.  In order to pass additional parameters to your application, such as image name, or image id, (if you're saving a reference to your image in your app), you need to pass them as form fields within the form.  HOWEVER when you then read this in your upload method, they are translated into PARAMETERS.  The nasty bit is that the dev environment is clever enough to read both form fields AND parameters, not so in production.